# Incluir Webassembly con Typescript (sin node)

Tags: typescript, rust

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma, lo más simple posible, de incluir webassembly con typescript, no uso node.
El caso que si activo la opción en tsconfig.json de "allowJs": true y muevo manualmente el archivo wasm si que funciona.
Esta solución no me parece muy limpia, puesto que tengo dos ficheros (glue) network_calculator_lib.js bastante parecidos, aún así probé si se podía compilar en la misma carpeta y como podía imaginar no, no se puede, no permite sobrescribir el fichero, por que lo considera, según he leído, parte de proyecto (y lo es).

Espero que me haya explicado medianamente bien, estoy usando Rust para compilar a Webassembly con wasm-pack (edito, puse webpack), aunque preferiría de poder, directamente importar el wasm.
De servidor estoy usando también uno escrito en Rust con actix web.

Disculpas y gracias por adelantado si pregunto algo muy bobo, pero la mayoría usa webpack/node y no he encontrado información que me aclare.

[image: Proyecto]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final este código resolvió mi problema:

```
import init, { exported_wasm_func } from '../pkg/network_calculator_lib.js';
async function run() {
    await init(); // Necesitas llamar a la función init antes de la función wasm exportada.
    document.body.textContent = exported_wasm_func();
}
run()
```

Para quien tenga problemas similares podría ayudar:

- Compilar Rust con la opción web target: `wasm-pack build --target web`.
- En HTML, el archívo o código JS debe ser de típo módulo: `<script type="module" src="./scripts/js/index.js"></script>`.
- En Cargo.toml:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
[dependencies]
wasm-bindgen = "0.2"
```

- El archivo Package.json realmente no es necesario.

Fuente: https://aralroca.com/blog/first-steps-webassembly-rust